# Admin/Role is not mapped to Azure groups

Tags: azure-ad

I followed the this [link](https://sitecoredude.com/how-to-integrate-azure-ad-with-sitecore-content-management-in-10-easy-steps/) to enable Azure AD as identity provider for my local Sitecore 10.1.3 instance. I can login with one of the user with admin groups mapped, but Sitecore gave me the following message:

[image]

it seems that the groups are not mapped to either admin or sitecore\author role. I developed a MVC app and verified that all groups of this user exist in the claim.

How do I troubleshoot this scenario? is there a way to know what claims send back to Sitecore identity server and how the map is done?

[Added new info]
In the log of identity server, there are some INFO not error like this:

```
2024-03-07T10:39:57.5610869-08:00 [INF] (Sitecore Identity/DEMO-SC101) Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://xp0identityserver.dev.local/signin-oidc application/x-www-form-urlencoded 2257
2024-03-07T10:39:57.5634166-08:00 [INF] (Sitecore Identity/DEMO-SC101) CORS policy execution failed.
2024-03-07T10:39:57.5635849-08:00 [INF] (Sitecore Identity/DEMO-SC101) Request origin "https://login.microsoftonline.com" does not have permission to access the resource.
2024-03-07T10:39:57.5637415-08:00 [INF] (Sitecore Identity/DEMO-SC101) No CORS policy found for the specified request.
```

[NEW] looks like login as user that was admin group, the admin flag will be set. but those users with content authors group, the role = "sitecore\author" is not set. even I manually add role "sitecore\author", after that user login, the role was removed.

```
                        <AzureGroupTransformation type="Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityProviders.DefaultClaimsTransformation, Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityProviders">
                            <SourceClaims>
                                <Claim1 type="groups" value="ba3a4750-1165-4082-bd3e-21d69d354f8c"/>
                            </SourceClaims>
                            <NewClaims>
                                <Claim1 type="role" value="sitecore\Author"/>
                                <Claim2 type="comment" />
                            </NewClaims>
                        </AzureGroupTransformation>
```

[Issue resolved]
**After add CORS origins and added comment claim to role map, magically everything works now.**

Thank you very much!
John

Comment: can you add the xml file which is doing the mapping between the roles from SC and Azure AD groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please verify your custom claims:

```
 <IdentityResources>
    <SitecoreIdentityResource>
        <Name>sitecore.profile</Name>
        <UserClaims>
            <UserClaim1>name</UserClaim1>
            <UserClaim2>email</UserClaim2>
            <UserClaim3>role</UserClaim3>
            <UserClaim4>http://www.sitecore.net/identity/claims/isAdmin</UserClaim4>
            <UserClaim5>http://www.sitecore.net/identity/claims/originalIssuer</UserClaim5>
            <UserClaim6>comment</UserClaim6>
            <UserClaim7>fullName</UserClaim7>
        </UserClaims>
        <Required>true</Required>
    </SitecoreIdentityResource>
</IdentityResources>
```

Also please verify the following configuration:

```
<ActiveDirectoryGroupTransformationAdmin type="Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityProviders.DefaultClaimsTransformation, Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityProviders">
    <SourceClaims>
        <Claim1 type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/group" value="Sitecore_Admin"/>
    </SourceClaims>
    <NewClaims>
        <Claim1 type="http://www.sitecore.net/identity/claims/isAdmin" value="true"/>
        <Claim2 type="comment"/>
    </NewClaims>
</ActiveDirectoryGroupTransformationAdmin>
```

From your logs of the identity server info it seems like this:

You are missing some AllowedCorsOrigins settings in the Identity Server `Allowed Cors Origins` setting.

See the blog post for more details: [Sitecore Identity Server in a nutshell](https://sitecore.merkle.com/sitecore-identity-server-in-a-nutshell/)

Comment: Thank you very much! just found out that if a user is part of admin group, that map works but map to sitecore\author does not work. even I manually add role to an AD user, after login, the roles added were all removed.

Comment: where do I inspect the comment claim?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the file **identityfolder/sitecore/Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityProvider.AzureAd/Config/Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityProvider.AzureAd.xml** you need to have next configuration for admin group users:

```
<AzureADUserToAdminUser type="Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityProviders.DefaultClaimsTransformation, Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityProviders">
  <SourceClaims>
    <Claim1 type="groups" value="aaa8caa0-aa32-46f0-1222-12cad423948d"/>
  </SourceClaims>
  <NewClaims>
      <Claim1 type="http://www.sitecore.net/identity/claims/isAdmin" value="true"/>
  </NewClaims>
</AzureADUserToAdminUser>
```

The id represent the ObjectID of AzureAD admin group

Comment: I have that settings changed